# Create an Activity with API changing

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I go to File > New > New Android Application and enter the following:

[image]

then I click Next and tells me that I can't "Create Activity" and then again in the "New Android Application" and enter the following:

[image]

it works and I can check "Create Activity"!

I making a simple thing in pages, text and I want to get map to some place using latitude and longitude through GPS,

My question is, will people who got Android version 2.2 mobile or higher can view everything?

Comment: Just in case, the SDK Manager in this http://oi59.tinypic.com/amdwec.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use read the Google Maps API doc, you can support 2.2 and above using Google Play Services SDK.

please check :

[Google Maps Android -  API V2 Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro)

[How to setup Google Play Services SDK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)